# Appcelerator Studio times out waiting for Android Emulator to launch

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I've run into a problem with launching my Android apps on my Virtual Devices after I recently updated my existing SDKs from the AVD Manager. When I choose my existing Android Emulator from Appcelerator Studio and hit run, it compiles fine, but once compiling is finished, it says the following:

```
[INFO] :   Signing apk: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner "-sigalg" "MD5withRSA" "-digestalg" "SHA1" "-keystore" "/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.3.v20151203125132/android/dev_keystore" "-storepass" "*******" "-signedjar" "/Users/<username>/Work/Appcelerator/<MyApp>/build/android/bin/<MyApp>.apk" "/Users/<username>/Work/Appcelerator/<MyApp>/build/android/bin/app-unsigned.apk" "tidev"
[INFO] :   Aligning zip file: /Users/<username>/.android/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign "-v" "4" "/Users/<username>/Work/Appcelerator/<MyApp>/build/android/bin/<MyApp>.apk" "/Users/<username>/Work/Appcelerator/<MyApp>/build/android/bin/<MyApp>.apkz"
[INFO] :   Writing build manifest: /Users/<username>/Work/Appcelerator/<MyApp>/build/android/build-manifest.json
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Waiting for emulator to become ready...
[LiveView] version 1.0.9
[LiveView] File Server Started on Port 8324
[LiveView] Alloy project monitor started
[LiveView] Event Server Started on Port 8323
[TRACE] :  Timed out while waiting for the emulator to boot; waited 240000 ms
[ERROR] :  Emulator timeout after waiting 240000 ms
```

The strange thing is, the emulator does launch and boots up properly, but Appcelerator Studio seems to not "see" that the emulator has launched, so it keeps waiting and eventually times out. Creating new virtual devices does not eradicate the issue.

This issue occurs with LiveView enabled and disabled.

My environment is:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.4.2
  npm Version                 = 3.8.5

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.31

Titanium SDK
  5.0.3.v20151203125132

Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools          = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Installed                   = yes
  Memory Limit                = 2 GB
```

Here are my installed SDKs:

[image: Installed Android SDKs and SDK addons]

Things were working fine before I updated the installed Android SDKs a couple of days ago. This issue has made Android development using Appcelerator Studio extremely painful, slow and unproductive, with no debugging possible in Studio and having to manually compile and install APKs to the AVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Titanium SDK version 5.0.3 is quite old. Can you try with the latest SDK 5.4 GA and Studio 4.7.0 GA.

Comment: Thanks, using SDK 5.4.0 GA did work! Any idea why using v5.0.3 breaks functionality?